# How to propagate context between two services communicating via rabbitmq in opentelemetry?

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq, open-telemetry, node-amqplib

I am trying to find a way to propagate context between two services communicating via rabbitmq in opentelemetry. There was an article for doing similar in Go [article link](https://devandchill.com/posts/2021/12/go-step-by-step-guide-for-implementing-tracing-on-a-microservices-architecture-2/2/) but unable to implement it in node.

There are two approaches I am considering

1. Pass context in header of message published via broker.
   Or
2. Create a child span based on the traceId and spanId. [answer link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70378025/how-to-create-opentelemetry-span-from-a-string-traceid) there's an answer for this in Go, but couldn't find a way to create a new span.

Is there any code reference available to perform any of the above?

Answer (score 0):

Opentelemetry Node already has plugin for the amqp lib which already does the work for you i.e [inject](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-js-contrib/blob/main/plugins/node/instrumentation-amqplib/src/amqplib.ts#L649)/[extract](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-js-contrib/blob/main/plugins/node/instrumentation-amqplib/src/amqplib.ts#L407) context https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-js-contrib/tree/main/plugins/node/instrumentation-amqplib.